# How do you create a stretched beta distribution with Scipy using only quantiles?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, scipy.stats

I am trying to recreate a stretched beta distribution that is output by one of my companies’ internal tools. This tool is quite dated and I am trying to come up with a replacement for it.
The initial tool asks the user for P90/P50/P10 quantile values. It does not ask the user for the alpha or beta values. Therefore, I need to figure out how to make a stretched beta distribution based only on quantile data.

For example, I want to find a stretched beta distribution for an area of a polygon. The p90 value is 100 acres, the P50 value is 250 acres, and the P10 value is 500 acres
I cannot figure out how to do this in Scipy (or any other library for that matter).
I can’t figure out how to estimate the alpha and beta factors. I feel like if I can derive the alpha and beta factors, I could use the loc and scale values to potentially constrain the distribution.

I have tried to read the Scipy documentation and to be honest, i can’t understand it. I am not a statistician, and the documentation seems to assume a good amount of familiarity with statistics.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how to tackle this problem? If I can derive the alpha and beta values, am I right in thinking I should be able to use the loc and scale values to constrain and replicate the distribution?

Please let me know if I can provide any clarification.
[image: Example Distribution]

[image: Numerical values]

Comment: To avoid any possible confusion: what is your definition of a *stretched* beta distribution? What are its parameters?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser that is another thing that I am confused on. "Stretched Beta Distribution" seems to have been a term in Vogue 20 years ago but I can find little documentation about it on the internet. What I assume this means is that I am trying to generate a "Un Standard Beta distribution" as described in this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186465/difference-between-standard-beta-and-unstandard-beta-distributions   . The reason I think it is un-standard is that my values will be outside the normal range of 0-1

Comment: Perhaps we can make a reasonable guess.  For the example that you gave (P90, P50 and P10 values), can you add the result given by your internal tool to the question?

Comment: It seems plausible that "stretched" means rescaled from (0, 1) to (0, something) and then shifted to (something else, something + something else). So in addition to the usual alpha and beta, there are also offset and scale.

Comment: It seems like maybe the quantiles are stated in reverse order? i.e. maybe it should be P10 = 100 and P90 = 500 instead of vice versa.

Comment: @RobertDodier (responding to your first comment), yes, and in the SciPy implementation, these would be the `loc` and `scale` parameters.  With only three quantiles specified, the system to solve for the beta parameters (`a`, `b`, `loc` and `scale`) is underdetermined.  If, perhaps, the internal tool assumes the left end of the support is 0, then there are just three parameters, `a`, `b`, and `scale`, and these can be found numerically from the given data.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I have updated the post to show the theoretical distribution from the tool

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser,  a assumption of 0 isnt a bad assumption as the tool attempts to estimate for physical parameters that cannot be less than 0

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like the given values (F90, F10) are actually inverse of the complementary CDF (this is related to @RobertDodier comment above about the values being in the reverse order).  Does your software show the numerical values of the parameters of the stretched beta distribution?  What are the numerical values of the support limits and the exponents?

Comment: *"... assumption of 0 isnt a bad assumption"* But the plot makes it look like it used approximately 40 for the low end of the support.

Comment: `@WarrenWeckesser i have updated the original post to include all the numerical data that the tool gives on the distribution

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser ya i see that it gets cutoff at 40....not sure why though

Comment: In principal one can find 3 parameters from the 3 equations (cdf(x1) = 0.1, cdf(x2) = 0.5, and cdf(x3) = 0.9) and maybe there's something in Scipy for that. A speed bump you might encounter is that the beta cdf involves the incomplete beta function, and many common approaches for numerical solutions will want to differentiate that with respect to the parameters; Maxima (https://maxima.sourceforge.io) says the derivatives involve regularized hypergeometric functions. Probably Scipy knows about that, so maybe there's no problem.

Comment: @JosiahHulsey, I think you'll need to dig into the documentation (or source code) of your internal tool to find out how it (apparently) solves for four parameters when there are only three equations implied by the given data.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The table given by OP implies that they chose 33.3 as the offset. Josiah, if different tries all have min = 33.3, then that clinches it; you can assume the same.

Comment: Josiah, I've posted a complete solution for Maxima, sorry it's not Python. Hope it helps in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't take the time right now to post all of the details, but I can confirm that the general strategy of solving 3 equations for 3 parameters (a, b, and scale parameter) does work; I was able to recover the solution shown by OP.

(1) System of 3 equations: evaluate cdf(x_k) = quantile_k for x_1 = 100, x_2 = 250, x_3 = 500, and quantile_1 = 1/10, quantile_2 = 1/2, quantile_3 = 9/10.

cdf for a general beta distribution is

```
beta_incomplete_regularized(a, b, (x - x0)/L)
```

where x0 is the offset (33.3 above) and L is the scale. (Scipy notation may differ.)

(2) Jacobian matrix. Differentiate cdf(x_k) with respect to a, b, and L, giving 3 gradients. Construct a matrix, with those gradients as the rows. Maxima says the derivative is

```
[beta_incomplete_regularized(a,b,(x-x0)/L)
  *(log((x-x0)/L)+psi[0](b+a)-psi[0](a))
  -(gamma(a)*hypergeometric_regularized([a,a,1-b],[a+1,a+1],(x-x0)/L)
            *gamma(b+a)*(x-x0)^a)
   /(L^a*gamma(b)),
 (gamma(b)*gamma(b+a)
          *hypergeometric_regularized([b,b,1-a],[b+1,b+1],1-(x-x0)/L)
          *(1-(x-x0)/L)^b)
  /gamma(a)
  +beta_incomplete_regularized(b,a,1-(x-x0)/L)
   *((-log(1-(x-x0)/L))-psi[0](b+a)+psi[0](b)),
 -(L^((-a)-1)*(1-(x-x0)/L)^(b-1)*(x-x0)^a)/beta(a,b)]
```

The regularized hypergeometric function is the 3F2 function divided by the product of gamma(n[k]) where n is the second list of parameters.

A quick web search seems to suggest Scipy doesn't implement 3F2, so that might be a roadblock. But I didn't look very hard.

(3) Supply equations and Jacobian to multidimensional Newton algorithm.

Sorry that I can't give a full solution, or in Python, right now. Hope this helps all the same.

EDIT: Here's a complete solution for Maxima.

```
display2d: false;
linel: 65;

/* construct cdf for stretched beta */
assume (x > 0, L > 0, x0 > 0);
assume (x > x0, x < x0 + L);
assume (a > 0, b > 0);
load (distrib);
cdf: cdf_beta ((x - x0)/L, a, b);

/* construct gradient wrt free parameters a, b, L */
grad_e: [diff (cdf, a), diff (cdf, b), diff (cdf, L)];
expand_hypergeometric_regularized: lambda ([aa, bb, xx], hypergeometric (aa, bb, xx) / product (gamma (bb[k]), k, 1, length (bb)));
grad_e1: subst (hypergeometric_regularized = expand_hypergeometric_regularized, grad_e);

/* construct equations given user-specified data */
x0_assumed: 333/10;
F90: 100;
Median: 250;
F10: 500;
eqs_with_x0: [subst (x = F90, cdf) = 1/10, subst (x = Median, cdf) = 1/2, subst (x = F10, cdf) = 9/10];
eqs: subst (x0 = x0_assumed, eqs_with_x0);

/* construct Jacobian matrix by evaluating gradient at data values */
DF_with_x0: apply ('matrix, makelist (subst (x = xx, grad_e1), xx, [F90, Median, F10]));
DF: subst (x0 = x0_assumed, DF_with_x0);

/* solve equations via multidimensional Newton algorithm */
load (mnewton);
newtondebug: true;
/* need initial guess; assume cdf is skewed to the right, so a < b
 * and guess L is somewhat bigger than interquantile range
 */
solution: mnewton (eqs, [a, b, L], [2, 3, 600], DF);

/* test solution in equations */
float (subst (solution[1], eqs));

/* display pdf of beta distribution */
pdf: subst (x0 = x0_assumed, subst (solution[1], pdf_beta ((x - x0)/L, a, b)));
plot2d (pdf, [x, x0_assumed, x0_assumed + assoc (L, solution[1])]);

/* mean and sd */
printf (true, "Mean ~,1f", subst (solution[1], mean_beta (a, b) * L + x0_assumed));
printf (true, "Std ~,1f", subst (solution[1], std_beta (a, b) * L));

/* table of quantiles */
quantile: subst (solution[1], lambda ([q], quantile_beta (q, a, b) * L + x0_assumed));
for p in [100, 95, 90, 75, 50, 25, 10, 5, 0]
    do printf (true, "F~d ~,1f~%", p, quantile(1 - p/100));
```

Here's the solution I get:

```
[a = 1.782967949218066,b = 7.660029561011594,
         L = 1301.704394701864]
```

and the output:

```
Mean 279.1
Std 157.6
F100 33.3
F95 76.6
F90 100.0
F75 157.2
F50 250.0
F25 371.8
F10 500.0
F5 581.7
F0 1335.0
```